# How to delete a list parameters but not the contents?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, urllib

I have a problem where the I will get info from an API and the info will be returned like:

```
[{"market_id":"16","coin":"Dogecoin","code":"DOGE","exchange":"BTC","last_price":"0.00000025","yesterday_price":"0.00000025","change":"0.00","24hhigh":"0.00000026","24hlow":"0.00000025","24hvol":"6.732","top_bid":"0.00000025","top_ask":"0.00000026"}]
```

That makes it really hard to call the price for example. So I was wondering if there would be a way to get rid of the list  `[ ]` and still keep that data? Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Looks like [JSON](http://json.org) to me. You should look into a JSON parser for this.

Comment: I looked Ctrl+F the website for JSON and I found that it is in JSON. Thanks for realizing that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure -- I'm assuming you've already parsed the JSON -- and since you only want to keep the first element (because there apparently is only one element), you can do:

```
data = data[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json
data = '[{"market_id":"16","coin":"Dogecoin","code":"DOGE","exchange":"BTC","last_price":"0.00000025","yesterday_price":"0.00000025","change":"0.00","24hhigh":"0.00000026","24hlow":"0.00000025","24hvol":"6.732","top_bid":"0.00000025","top_ask":"0.00000026"}]'
# since the list only contains one element (the dict), we'll access it with [0]
dictionary = json.loads(data)[0]
print dictionary["last_price"]
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`. Thanks!

Comment: @user3818089 Yes, thats because your example is a list, not a str. But I think you forgot the quotes in your question details, and it's actually a JSON str (not a list). Take a look at my edit.